Does this sound like a "fried" audio interface?
I've had a Steinberg UR22mkII for a few years and it has been working excellent. Last week, my laptops docking station broke down, so I ordered a new one. Before I ordered it, Dells customer service ensured me that the new dock, a Dell WD19S 180 W, would be able to provide power to the audio interface via USB. But immediately after plugging it in, I'm hearing recurring disturbances, about once a minute. I've recorded it straight from the headphone, attaching an audio file you can find on my OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/u/c/d0b365217d507450/EdtCorIwrORHlSniyWdnPucBvZm8hEcnEH9IxLP4837Q7A?e=dKgDJw
I've tried to isolate the source of the issue, but even when I plug the audio interface straight into the laptop, bypassing the new docking station, I still hear the issue. And when I try my other laptop, I see a different issue: the audio intermittently disappears for about half a second, while the light bulb on the UR22mkII that indicates USB power goes away.
Is my audio interface permanently damaged? And if so, do you think it's because of the new docking station? In that case, I don't know if I dare order a new audio interface in case the docking station fries that one too.
